# What data structure is used by window managers to map a mouse click at a specific point to a window?

Tags: data-structures, window-managers

I am currently preparing a presentation about Skewer-Trees [(Edelsbrunner, Haring and Hilbert)](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~edels/Papers/1986-J-05-RectangularPointLocation.pdf) and am struggling to find practical applications for this data structure. My professor suggested, that skewer-trees are used by window managers to find which window was targeted by a mouse click.

This seems like an overkill to me and i would have thought a window manager uses lists to represent the windows on the screen.

2-dimensional Skewer-Trees can be constructed in O(n log n) time and require O(log^2 n) time to find which rectangle contains a given point. n is the number of rectangles stored in the tree.

Comment: You don't have to use the most sophisticated data structure, but an OS which starts lagging when you click rapidly in one of forty windows has a problem. Moreover, you don't just need to find the window: you also have to detect which widget (e.g. button, or background) was hit. That may become a lot of rectangles on a busy desktop.

Comment: the thing is, using simple lists you could reposition windows in O(1) time and search in O(n) time.
Skewer-Trees search faster (O(log^2 n)), but have to be rebuild after repositioning a window in O(n log n) time.
That means, plain lists are better if the average amount of clicks  done by the user before repositioning a window is less than a specific value.
it feels like the amount of user clicks required between repositioning is to big to justify the usage of the Skewer-Trees

Comment: I'm not saying Skewer trees specifically are a good choice for that use case. But better-than-linear search times can't hurt. I for instance click a lot (and others who are not as fond of shurtcuts probably click even more) but rarely move windows.